# How to sort JSON Array and present it in UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have a following JSON Array

```
 {
  "id": 36,
  "name": "The Shawshank Redemption",
  "year": 1994,
  "rating": 9.196
},
{
  "id": 45,
  "name": "The Green Mile",
  "year": 1999,
  "rating": 9.064
},
{
  "id": 48,
  "name": "Forrest Gump",
  "year": 1994,
  "rating": 8.921
},
{
  "id": 39,
  "name": "Schindler's List",
  "year": 1993,
  "rating": 8.817
},
{
  "id": 53,
  "name": "Intouchables",
  "year": 2011,
  "rating": 8.812
},
```

So, how to make films with the same years in the UITableView be shown in one section (for example: "The Shawshank Redemption" and "Forrest Gump" will be shown in section "1994", "The Green Mile" will be shown in section "1999" and etc.)

Also sections with films must sorted by year ("2011" section first, then "1999" section and etc.) and films in each section must be sorted by rating (for example, in "1994" section "The Shawshank Redemption" must be at row 0 and "Forrest Gump" at row 1)

My solution for this is to make 2d-array and place films with the same years into it, but I am sure there's must be a better solution for this.

Comment: You could group the array by year with `Dictionary(grouping:by:` and map the dictionary using sorted keys to a custom struct holding the name/year of the section and an array of `Film` sorted by rating

Comment: What you do is a BuckeSort, this is very efficient if you have more movies than years and a good way to limit the number or years you need in advance. This seems possible for your application and it seems pretty adequate if you have more movies than years. However, since you will usually want to put the movies into some other data structure than an array there might be more appropriate solutions depending on the details.

Answer (score -1):

**First**: Create a Custom Element

**Second**: Read Json and create an array as Custom Array and append to this array

**Third**: Create Tuple for sections

**Forth**: Code to UITableView

Comment: Don't do *Third*. Apple says: ***Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They’re not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.***

Comment: I use structs generally but when i want to sort custom array by dates , i use tuples